# js toolip scrash

Tags: php, javascript

I've problem with js toolip. I use one fine from http://ara-abcarians.com/jquery/atooltip/. The text is loading from MySQL database.

```
echo "<td nowrap='nowrap'> <a href=\"#\" class=\"clickTip exampleTip\" ";
echo "title1=\" ".$row['text']." \" ";
echo "> aaaaa </a></td>";
```

The text from dbase is with a formated image

```
<img style="float: left;" src="./public/repository/images/2n0lcud.gif" alt="" width="350" height="76" />
```

and the ending visualisation is crashing.

```
2011-10-28  00:05:15  3  
2011-10-29  23:54:15  4  
2011-10-30  11:43:01  żźćńąśłęó ŻŹĆŃĄŚŁĘÓ "> 5  
2011-10-31  01:26:05  a1  
2011-10-31  01:26:33  a2  


2011-10-30  11:43:01  żźćńąśłęó ŻŹĆŃĄŚŁĘÓ "> 5
```

where

```
żźćńąśłęó ŻŹĆŃĄŚŁĘÓ - a piece of main text of the news - not to show (at this moment)
"> - element of the html/php code - of course not to show
5 - title of the news - only this can be show
```

I change the code to:

```
echo "title1=' ".$row['text']." ' ";
```

and no crashing visualisation in old point

```
2011-10-28  00:05:15  3  
2011-10-29  23:54:15  4  
2011-10-30  11:43:01  5  
2011-10-31  01:26:05  a1  
2011-10-31  01:26:33  a2
```

but a crash is now in a new point

```
2011-10-28  00:05:15  '>3  
2011-10-29  23:54:15  4  
2011-10-30  11:43:01  5  
2011-10-31  01:26:05  a1  
2011-10-31  01:26:33  a2
```

in the main text (from title 3) I've

```
xxxx'fffff 999999/666666
```

when I try to display the text (of the news) I see only

```
xxxx
```

(The text was loading into dbase via tiny_mce and the code)

```
addslashes($text)
```

Maybe any suggestion how to fix it?
brgs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `htmlspecialchars` with the `ENT_QUOTES` option, addslashes should be used to escape input not output!